# django user inherited model fail

Tags: python, django, inheritance, continuous-integration, codeship

I have a model inhereting from Auth.User model, this way:
class UsuarioWeb(User):
 # more fields
And in Codeship when making tests, it fails with this error:

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve
>   bases for [] This can happen
>   if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g.
>   contrib.auth) in an app with no migrations; see
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#dependencies
>   for more (python3_venv)

I understand the error and it could be solved by a OneToOneField.
So one question is, Am I doing right inheriting this way?
And other, how to solve this error doing this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a custom user model and do not want to use a `OneToOneField`, make the class inherit `AbstractBaseUser` instead. This class only includes authentication functions. If, however, you want the regular `User` model fields included, make your custom class inherit `AbstractUser`. The user classes are found in `django.contrib.auth.models`.

Comment: thank you very much. So, I am inheriting from the wrong model.

Comment: Which way do you think is better? inherit from AbstractUser or add a OneToOneField.

Comment: I personally use a `OneToOneField`.  It is mostly personal preference.

Comment: @user2791312 If this answer has helped, please consider marking that it has answered your question. Good luck with your Django project!